# Knockout binding isn't working

Tags: knockout.js

Why knockout binding isn't working on the following code

```
ko.components.register('like-widget', {
    template: "<input data-bind=\"value: firstName\" />"
});

ko.applyBindings()

$('#btnAdd').on('click', function() {
    var $newWidget = $('<like-widget>');
    $('#addZone').append($newWidget);
    ko.applyBindings({ firstName: ko.observable("Bert") }, $newWidget[0]);
});
```

Comment: Could you paste your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you've chosen (using jQuery), isn't very "knockout-like". Still it can be done:

In your html markup, you need to explicitly tell knockout which parameters to use in the component's viewmodel (use `params=""`)

```js
ko.components.register('like-widget', {
  template: "<input data-bind=\"value: firstName\" />"
});

ko.applyBindings({})

$('#btnAdd').on('click', function() {
  var $newWidget = $('<like-widget params="firstName: firstName">');
  $('#addZone').append($newWidget);


  ko.applyBindings({
    firstName: ko.observable("Bert")
  }, $newWidget[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="addZone"></div>
<button id="btnAdd">add</button>
```

My suggestion however, is to use a `click` binding and an `observableArray` of widget viewmodels.

```js
var components = ko.observableArray([]);
var addComponent = function() {
  components.push({
    firstName: "Bert"
  });
}

ko.components.register('like-widget', {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(params.firstName || '');
  },
  template: "<input data-bind=\"value: firstName\" />"
});

ko.applyBindings({
  components: components,
  addComponent: addComponent
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: components">
  <like-widget params="firstName: firstName" />
</div>

<button data-bind="click: addComponent">add</button>
```